# Show that $T$ is a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

We will define a transformation $T$ from $\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ to $F(\mathbb{R}^{m},\mathbb{R}^{n})$ which is the space of all functions from $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. For a matrix $A$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, the value $T(A)$ will be a function from $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$; thus, we need to define $(T(A))(\vec{v})$ for a vector $\vec{v}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$. We let $(T(A))(\vec{v})=A\vec{v}$.

Show that T is a linear transformation.

I know you have to show T is closed under scalar multiplication and addition, but I don't know how to show that when the output is a function. So I tried:

$T(A)=f$ where $f$ is a function.

Let $k$ be a scalar.
$T(kA)=kf=kT(A)$

So T is closed under scalar multiplication.

Let $B$ be a matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$.

$T(A+B)=f_{A+B}=f_A + f_B=T(A)+T(B)$

So T is closed under addition.

But am I allowed to just go from  $f_{A+B}=f_A + f_B$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown anything. For example, how do you know that if $f = T(A)$ and $g=T(kA)$, that $g = kf$? You don't, this is what you have to prove. Similarly for additivity, you have just rewritten what you need to prove without proving anything.

It will not be fruitful to just rename $T(A)$ with $f$, if that would work, you would be able to show that any function is linear. Therefore, you must use definition of $T$ directly:

$$T(\alpha A + \beta B)v = (\alpha A+\beta B)v = \alpha Av + \beta Bv = \alpha T(A)v + \beta T(B)v,\ \forall v\in\Bbb R^n$$

which implies $$T(\alpha A + \beta B)=\alpha T(A) + \beta T(B).$$